I have been struggling to knit my project in rstudio, neither PDF, word, HTML or tinytex are working
Rmarkdown file is not knitting, I am continously getting this error code.
processing file: cyclistic-bike-share-analysis---r-markdown-save.Rmd
  |.                                          |   2% [unnamed-chunk-1]         
Quitting from lines 59-185 [unnamed-chunk-1] (cyclistic-bike-share-analysis---r-markdown-save.Rmd)
                                                                                                                     
Error in `contrib.url()`:
! trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Backtrace:
 1. utils::install.packages("data.table")
 2. utils::contrib.url(repos, "source")
Execution halted

when i remove install.packages("data.table") from the code, i get the same error but for a different packages.
I am expecting to be able to knit my project in pdf, html or word format without any errors.

Don't include lines of code for commands that only need to be run once, such as installing packages. Once they're on your computer, you're good to go. Just call on those packages using library().

"@Phil I have removed all lines of 'installed.packages' from the code chunk, and now i am getting this error. |..............................                      |  57% [unnamed-chunk-1]
processing file: DF-M-DF,.Rmd
Quitting from lines 63-159 [unnamed-chunk-2] (DF-M-DF,.Rmd)
Error in tinytex::install_tinytex():
! If you want to force installing TinyTeX anyway, use tinytex::install_tinytex(force = TRUE).
Backtrace:

tinytex::install_tinytex()
Execution halted


Same issue, tinytex::install_tinytex() is not something to be done every time.
